# How do take the values from a large JSON response with multiple arrays and brackets?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I have a JSON response (over 500lines) , that has several arrays and brackets inside. Basically an overly nested response.

I am using Alamofire for fetching and i get a JSONData as response. But I don't know how to take values from the response and print it on a custom cell .

I am using Alamofire 5 to get the JSON response.

Please excuse if this sounds too newbieish , I am new to iOS developing.

```
{
    "availabilityResultList": [
        {
            "availabilityRouteList": [
                {
                    "availabilityByDateList": [
                        {
                            "originDestinationOptionList": [
                                {
                                    "fareComponentGroupList": [
                                        {
                                            "boundList": [
                                                {
                                                    "availFlightSegmentList": [
                                                        {
                                                            "addOnSegment": false,
                                                            "flightSegment": {
                                                                "journeyDuration": "PT1H15M",
                                                                "distance": 1,
                                                                "departureAirport": {
                                                                    "locationName": "LOC",
                                                                    "cityInfo": {
                                                                        "country": {
                                                                            "locationName": "LOC",
                                                                            "currency": {
                                                                                "code": "USD"
                                                                            },
                                                                            "locationCode": "LOC",
                                                                            "locationNameLanguage": "EN"
                                                                        },
                                                                        "city": {
                                                                            "locationName": "LOC",
                                                                            "locationCode": "LOC",
                                                                            "locationNameLanguage": "EN"
                                                                        }
                                                                    },
                                                                    "codeContext": "ASD",
                                                                    "language": "EN",
                                                                    "locationCode": "LOC"
                                                                },
                                                                "equipment": {
                                                                    "airEquipType": "ABC",
                                                                    "changeofGauge": false
                                                                },
                                                                "remark": "NO",
                                                                "ticketType": "PP",
                                                                "onTimeRate": 0,
                                                                "flightNotes": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "deiCode": 0
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "flightSegmentID": "",
                                                                "flownMileageQty": 0,
                                                                "flightNumber": "106",
                                                                "groundDuration": "",
                                                                "trafficRestriction": {
                                                                    "code": "",
                                                                    "explanation": {}
                                                                },
                                                                "stopQuantity": 0,
                                                                "codeshare": false,
                                                                "secureFlightDataRequired": false,
                                                                "departureDateTime": {
                                                                    "month": 5,
                                                                    "hour": 6,
                                                                    "year": 2019,
                                                                    "timezone": 270,
                                                                    "day": 6,
                                                                    "minute": 45,
                                                                    "second": 0
                                                                },
                                                                "ondControlled": false,
                                                                "arrivalDateTime": {
                                                                    "month": 5,
                                                                    "hour": 8,
                                                                    "year": 2019,
                                                                    "timezone": 270,
                                                                    "day": 6,
                                                                    "minute": 0,
                                                                    "second": 0
                                                                },
                                                                "airline": {
                                                                    "code": "RQ"
                                                                },
                                                                "arrivalAirport": {
                                                                    "locationName": "LOC",
                                                                    "cityInfo": {
                                                                        "country": {
                                                                            "locationName": "AA",
                                                                            "currency": {
                                                                                "code": "USD"
                                                                            },
                                                                            "locationCode": "AA",
                                                                            "locationNameLanguage": "EN"
                                                                        },
                                                                        "city": {
                                                                            "locationName": "loc",
                                                                            "locationCode": "LOC",
                                                                            "locationNameLanguage": "EN"
                                                                        }
                                                                    },
                                                                    "codeContext": "ASD",
                                                                    "language": "EN",
                                                                    "locationCode": "LOC"
                                                                },
                                                                "sector": "ASD",
                                                                "accumulatedDuration": ""
                                                            },
                                                            "marriageGroup": "-1"
                                                        }
                                                    ],
                                                    "boundCode": "Outbound"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
```

Comment: What is the value you're trying to display and what have you tried so far using swiftyjson?

Comment: Don't use swiftyjson, use the built-in json support, `Codeable`. There are plenty of info about it on the net and Q&A here at SO. You can use https://app.quicktype.io/ to get the swift structure that corresponds to your json message which will give you a good start

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: @Mohammad Reza Farahani I am trying to display journey duration , distance, location name ,code ,location code , city , ticket type , remark, flight number, stopQuantity, departureDateTime, arrivalDateTime, (from arrivalairport -> location name, location code,) and marriage code

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Thank you, I didn't know about that website. I am trying it now.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik 

I tried getting each value with swiftyjson (JsonData ["availabilityResultList"][0]["availabilityRouteList"][0]["availabilityByDateList"][0]["originDestinationOptionList"][0]["fareComponentGroupList"][0]["boundList"][0]["availFlightSegmentList"][0] ......)

But doing this for each value is hard, is there any better way to do this? (using codables as the other person said but I don't know much about codables)

and I want the data to be presented in custom cell that's reused (depending on count)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON is a very simple format and easy to read. There are only two different collection types and four value types.

- `{}` is a dictionary and is subscripted by key
- `[]` is an array and is subscripted by index (zero-based)

---

- Everything in double quotes is `String`, even `"123"` and `"false"`
- `false` and `true` is `Bool`
- Numeric values are `Double`, without fractional digits `Int`
- `<null>` is `NSNull`

With SwiftyJSON you get `distance` in `flightSegment` with (`root` represents the top level object`)

```
root["availabilityResultList"][0]["availabilityRouteList"][0]["availabilityByDateList"][0]["originDestinationOptionList"][0]["fareComponentGroupList"][0]["boundList"][0]["availFlightSegmentList"][0]["flightSegment"]["distance"]
```

Comment: I tried this but having to do this for each and every item is pretty hard (and I think bad practice) . I am looking for a much faster / easier way.Is there one?

Comment: In practice there is no difference to `Codable`. You can only use shorter names. With structs you get `distance` with `root.availabilityResultList.first.availabilityRouteList.first.availabilityByDateList.first.originDestinationOptionList.first.fareComponentGroupList.first.boundList.first.availFlightSegmentList.first.flightSegment.distance`. You could assign the object of `availFlightSegmentList` to a variable and navigate from there

Comment: If I use this method, how will I get the data into labels in custom cells thats reused? ( if I use this same code, I get the data for the first cell, how can I get the data for the remaining cells (if there are). Like , there are 3 flights available , and each flight has all these details and each cell shows the details of a single flight.)

Comment: See my first edited comment. Assign the array containing the flights (once) to a variable and navigate from there.